# Does the old English second person verb ending -est (eg thou comest) come from Latin conjugation?

Tags: etymology, language-evolution, conjugation, proto-indo-european

I feel like the question has all the information but yeah I'm just curious if the Latin verb endings influenced the old English -est endings.

Answer (score 7):

Nope! They're independent of each other. But I can see how easy it is to make that mistake, since they both come from the same source.

Both Old English and Latin are Indo-European languages, and they both independently retain Proto-Indo-European (PIE) conjugation. PIE's 2nd person singular present has been reconstructed as -si, which in Latin became -s and in Germanic -zi. Old English further developed the -zi into -st.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-est#Etymology_2) has the etymology:

> From Middle English -est, -st, from Old English -est, -ast, -st, ultimately from Proto-Germanic *-zi, from Proto-Indo-European *-si. The -t was by transfer from inverted order where thou followed the verb, which also occurred in most dialects of Middle Dutch and Middle High German (compare modern German -st).

You can find the fuller paradigm in [Sihler's New Comparative Grammar of Greek and Latin](https://books.google.com/books/about/New_Comparative_Grammar_of_Greek_and_Lat.html?id=IeHmqKY2BqoC).

| Number | Person | Athematic | Thematic |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Singular | 1st | *-mi | *-oh₂ |
|  | 2nd | *-si | *-esi |
|  | 3rd | *-ti | *-eti |
| Dual | 1st | *-wos | *-owos |
|  | 2nd | *-th₁es | *-eth₁es |
|  | 3rd | *-tes | *-etes |
| Plural | 1st | *-mos | *-omos |
|  | 2nd | *-te | *-ete |
|  | 3rd | *-nti | *-onti |